# XML-RPC server in EJB module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, xml-rpc

I'm wondering if it is possible to create XML-RPC server component within EJB module without servlets. I know EJB typically uses RMI as communication protocol but what if I want to omit RMI. What if i want to exchange data between EJB and web module (WAR) or other clients by different way like XML-RPC.

**Can EJB-module work as stand-alone unit which will expose its state and services as XML-RPC server?**

I still can do EJB module connected with WAR via RMI while this WAR will expose those services via servlet. Then other WARs or whatever-they-are clients can call this first WAR. Is this right or there is some other possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is to use [Spring Remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) to expose your EJBs via for instance JAX-WS. Spring will create automatically servlets for handling the requests for you. The bad news is that you have to call your EJBs from the remoting services you build - meaning some boilerplate code. It should be quite straight forward though.

An other possibility you might take a look at is [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) which can be used to build restful services.

Answer (score 0):

In EJB3, your service beans are just annotated POJOs. You can simply annotate the same POJOs with @WebService (and the rest of this family of annotations) to expose the same services as web services.

I realize this isn't strictly what you asked for as the implementation for services exposed in this way is JAX-WS which uses SOAP messages. But I think it achieves your intent.